# Controlling CodeModel's code output formatting: putting lines between namespace declarations

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vsx, c#-code-model

I'm making some experiments with Visual Studio's CodeModel. I tried creating a file with two namespaces in there through VS's Code Model:

```
CodeModel codeModel = projItem.ContainingProject.CodeModel;
codeModel.AddNamespace("Namespaces.FirstNamespace", "namespacestest.cs");
codeModel.AddNamespace("Namespaces.SecondNamespace", "namespacestest.cs");
```

the output of such code is:

```
//file namespacestest.cs
namespace Namespaces.FirstNamespace {
}
namespace Namespaces.SecondNamespace {
}
```

Which is **almost** what I'm looking for. The only catch here is that I'd like to control the spacing: having at least one line between the first and the second namespace. Does by chance anyone know of a way of achieving this?

This is what I want:

```
//file namespacestest.cs
namespace Namespaces.FirstNamespace {
}

namespace Namespaces.SecondNamespace {
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `codeModel.AddNamespace` will return you an object of CodeNamespace.
you can find the EditPoint of the namespace using the your first namespace and then insert a line like this.

```
CodeNamespace yournamespace = codeModel.AddNamespace(....);
EditPoint2 endEditPoint = yournamespace.GetEndPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartWhole).CreateEditPoint();
endEditPoint.InsertNewLine(1);
```

I am not sure whether this will put the line at the place you want but the idea is to get the EditPoint and then use it to insert the line.